# java ee 7 @Transactional on a servlet method

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a java ee 7 servlet with webservlet annotation. I have marked one of the methods of the servlet to be @Transactional. An entity manager is also provided to the servlet with a persistence context.

The method just uses the injected entity manager and persists a entity which is passed in as argument.

This method is invoked from the servlet while processing a http request. glassfish4 throws an exception saying that there is no transaction available.

I defined a simple managed CDI bean with the method and have  @Transactional annotation over it and entity manager injected.

I injected that object to the servlet and invoked the method from servlet and  everything works fine. em is injected to the CDI bean, transaction initiated and em.persist works fine.

Does this mean that a servlet object cannot have @Transactional annotation on its methods?

Comment: I'm not sure, may be servlets can not be proxied.

Comment: Correct, more or less.  Transactional is defined for CDI and EJB use.  i don't think it will work with Faces managed beans, Servlets, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make `@Transactional` work with `@WebServlet` and CDI on Wildfly 10 but **only when `@Transactional` is set on class level**. It does not work when it is set on method level.

So the following example works fine :

```
@Transactional
@WebServlet("/transactional")
public class TransactionalServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   /** The entity Manager */
   @Inject
   @AppStoreDatabase
   private EntityManager m_entityManager;

   @Override
   public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
   {
      final Person person = new Person();
      person.setFirstName("FirstName");
      person.setLastName("LastName");

      m_entityManager.persist(person);

      response.getWriter().println("OK");
   }
}
```

While annotating only the method does **NOT** work :

```
   @Transactional // Throws a TransactionRequiredException!
   @Override
   public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
   {
      final Person person = new Person();
      person.setFirstName("FirstName");
      person.setLastName("LastName");

      m_entityManager.persist(person);

      response.getWriter().println("OK");
   }
```

I will investigate.

Comment: Same result with TomEE plume 7.0.4 using session scoped CDI bean in JSF application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with TomEE plume 7.0.4. It does not throw an exception but no commit nor rollback occurred in my tests.

Conclusion is that `@Transactional` does not work in `@WebServlet`.

**Edit:** In these tests `@Transactional` was in method level. It seems to work in class level, see @Rouliboy's answer.

Comment: Regarding the javadoc `The javax.transaction.Transactional annotation provides the application the ability to declaratively control transaction boundaries` **on CDI managed beans, as well as classes defined as managed beans by the Java EE specification**. So it should work on a `@WebServlet` as it's a managed bean. I will give a try on wildfly and weblogic.

Comment: Related: it also does not work on JSF managed CDI beans in TomEE 7. Let us know if you see different results.

Comment: I tested it on Wildfly and it works when @Transactional is set on class level. It does not work when it is set on method level.